# Phonegap temporarily disable landscape mode

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

Im using Phonegap to create a game for Android.
I've created a lobby to search for opponents and to chat with other players.

When a player has found his opponent, he can play a game with him.

My problem is that the lobby need to be portrait only and the game landscape only. My config.xml (phonegap) let me only disable one.

Is there a way to temporarily disable one of the orientation modes in/with phonegap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this [plugin from yoik](https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation) which allows you to do that. Basic usage (from documentation)

```
// set to either landscape
screen.lockOrientation('landscape'); // Or portrait

// allow user rotate
screen.unlockOrientation();
```

Comment: Thx for the comment! I tried to make this plugin work, but it's keep saying: "setOrientation not supported on device".

Any idea?